# Disable play framework's select helper

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I have the following dropdown menu in my play(play for java, v2.3.4) template, how can I deactivate/disable it?

```
@select(setupForm("locationType"), options(LocationType.options()),
    '_label -> "Type",
    '_default -> "Choose a type",
    '_help -> "ATTENTION: you CANNOT change the type later.",
)
```

**P.S:**
I want it to be disabled, but still deliver it's value to the controller! I tried using javaScript to disable it, but when I disable it using JS, the value is not passed to the controller.

Comment: @biesior do you have any idea , how to do that? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a 'readonly' attribute?:

```
@select(setupForm("locationType"), options(LocationType.options()),
    '_label -> "Type",
    '_default -> "Choose a type",
    'readonly -> "readonly",
    '_help -> "ATTENTION: you CANNOT change the type later.",
)
```